# Transform ES6 imports into require.ensure with babel?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Is it possible with babel (or webpack or any other way) to transform all ES6 statements

```
import X from Y;
/* file body */
```

into

```
require.ensure(['Y'], 
  function() { 
    /* file body */
  });
```

Or isn't it?

Comment: Sure it's possible. But are you asking if a plugin exists already that performs the necessary transform? Haven't come across one myself.

Comment: How do you know if it is possible and if it is then why didn't anybody do that yet. For Install. Angular 2 would benefit very much if it could first load template and only later load http, module to load data.

Answer (score 0):

#### `.babelrc`

```
{
  "plugins": ["dynamic-import-webpack"]
}
```

https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack

Comment: This plugin transforms calls to `import()` (a proposal) rather than static import statements.